# iOS: Find out if an image is used in some xib

Tags: ios, objective-c, xib

I want to find out which images in the project are actually used. When I try to find names of images that were set programaticly, I can see them in the relevant classes when searching. This is not the case for images that were set in the xib. Is there some workaround to find if the image is used in some xib?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using the utility app [Unused](https://github.com/jeffhodnett/Unused) by Jeff Hodnett. I've used it before and had success with it.

Comment: Awesome, though I've noticed it doesn't work well with images referenced in source code and in plists (because of the potentially missing extensions such as '@2x' and .png). Use with caution, @Luda

Answer (score 2):

You can from the command line, yes.

As always, `grep` is your friend:

```
$ cd ~Source/Books/Beginning iOS 6 Development/ch04/Control Fun/Control Fun/en.lproj
$ grep png *
BIDViewController.xib:                          <string key="NSResourceName">apress_logo.png</string>
BIDViewController.xib:          <string key="NS.key.0">apress_logo.png</string>
```

Comment: your answer worked for me, but checked Ric Perrott's answer because it found all the unused images in 2 clicks. But thank you anyway. (I have up-voted your answer)